# Replicaiton and synchronizing to a central database

Tags: data-synchronization, replication

My client will have many outlets and each outlet will have a local db. But there is only one outlet which will have a central db. Ideally, my client wants to put everything on a cloud but due to the unreliable internet services where my clients operates, they decided to have a local db. Each local db will need push its data to the central db (one way only i.e. from local to the central db).

The database use will be MS SQL Server.

I am looking at Replication feature of the MS SQL and I think it will require Professional and above editions.

I am just wondering if there is other options? Maybe use other third party application to avoid costing or even other technologies?

Thanks in advance.